# Vlookup second largest value excel with multiple possible result

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

table `$A$1:$B$5`:

| ID | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 13 | A |
| 17 | B |
| 15 | C |
| 17 | D |

I can get the highest value in the `A8` with this formula:

`=IF(LARGE($A$2:$A$6; 1); INDEX($B$2:$B$6; MATCH(LARGE($A$2:$A$6; 1); $A$2:$A$6; 0)); "-")` | result: B

How can I get the second highest ID's Value in the A9? | expected result: D

I've tried to change the parameter of the LARGE formula to get the second highest ID and it did show the result of "17". But the result of the value is showing B.

`=IF(LARGE($A$2:$A$6; 2); INDEX($B$2:$B$6; MATCH(LARGE($A$2:$A$6; 2); $A$2:$A$6; 0)); "-")` | result: B

I also tried this formula:

`=IF(LARGE($A$2:$A$6; 2); VLOOKUP(LARGE($A$2:$A$6; 2);$A$1:$B$5;2;FALSE); "-")`| result: B

Comment: What is your excel version? Is it Excel365?

Comment: If you have access to `XMATCH()` then could try `=IF(LARGE($A$2:$A$6, 1), INDEX($B$2:$B$6, XMATCH(LARGE($A$2:$A$6, 1), $A$2:$A$6,0,-1)), "-")`.

Comment: @Harun24hr my excel version is Microsoft® Excel® 2019 MSO. I couldn't use the `XMATCH()`

Comment: Try my answer and feedback please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For ***Excel-2019*** you may try `AGGREGATE()` function.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(B2:B5,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(1:4)/(A2:A5=LARGE(A2:A5,1)),2)),"")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It did show the result I wanted. But can you explain what parameters inside the `AGGREGATE` function? I want to understand the use of that function

Comment: @stupirl `ROW(1:4)/(A2:A5=LARGE(A2:A5,1))`  will find all row number equal of `LARGE(A2:A5,1)` means `17`. `AGGREGATE(15,6......,2)` here 15 means small while 6 indicates to ignore errors. `2` meand find 2nd small which is row number 4 in data array. Here row 4 means `D` value.

Comment: why is it using 15 as small inside the parameter, instead of number large inside the parameter? doesn't it means the smallest number in data array? while 17 as a result is the largest number in data array

Comment: @stupirl `17` is large number but small means 2nd row number of largest values.